# Is b2Body::SetUserData deprecated

Tags: c++, box2d

I'm setting up a box2d body, using some old code for reference, in my old code I have right at the end of setting up the body, this line

```
body->SetUserData(this);
```

and if I look at the box2d source code, I can find this function

```
inline void b2Body::SetUserData(void* data)
{
    m_userData = data;
}
```

however when I try set this user data in my new project (using possibly a more up-to-date version of box2d), the function just does not exist.

Has the function been deprecated? Or have I somehow managed to remove a function that should be there?

Comment: Where do you look in the source code? How do you observer "the function just does not exist"?

Comment: @sehe In my other program it was directly above the getter, in my current project there was no function there. I did a `ctrl+f` for the setter, and every occurrence of the member variable being set, and the compilation error confirms the class has does not have the member `SetUserData`

Comment: You should include the error message.

Comment: @sehe I actually think I've just found the solution, im posting an answer

Comment: Good. I was still getting up to speed with the HelloWorld :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further investigation I found the function had been depracated, as the set up for user data had been changed to have a wrapper struct.

the old set up was as follows:

```
class b2Body
{
public:
    /// Get the user data pointer that was provided in the body definition.
    void* GetUserData() const;

    /// Set the user data. Use this to store your application specific data.
    void SetUserData(void* data);
 
private:
    void* m_userData;

};

inline void b2Body::SetUserData(void* data)
{
    m_userData = data;
}

inline void* b2Body::GetUserData() const
{
    return m_userData;
}
```

However this has now been changed to:

```
class B2_API b2Body
{
public:
    /// Get the user data pointer that was provided in the body definition.
    b2BodyUserData& GetUserData();

private:
    b2BodyUserData m_userData;

};

inline b2BodyUserData& b2Body::GetUserData()
{
    return m_userData;
}
```

Where this struct `b2BodyUserData` is defined as

```
struct B2_API b2BodyUserData
{
    b2BodyUserData()
    {
        pointer = 0;
    }

    /// For legacy compatibility
    uintptr_t pointer;
};
```

So the method to set user data no longer requires `SetUserData()`, as `GetUserData()` returns a `non-const` reference to this struct which can be modified, to give the same functionality.

Comment: Do you mean to:   `b2BodyUserData data = pBody[0]->GetUserData(); data.pointer = (uintptr_t)"mydata";`

Comment: @nephewtom Yes precisely, this is the way it is done now

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it can be used in the body and also in the body definition. For example, doing something like: `struct Entity { b2BodyDef def; Entity() { def.userData.pointer = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this); ... }`. By the way, nice game `Polychrome`! Inspired by HUE?

Comment: @nephewtom thanks :D
Everyone asks that, maybe subconsciously but we forgot HUE existed when making it aha